# Rey's familial ties in “The Force Awakens”

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

In an [answer on another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111059/16378) about *The Force Awakens*, the author suggests that:

> Rey is Luke’s daughter.

I’ve missed any indicators of any such relationship while watching the movie.

> For instance, I took neither Luke’s lightsaber calling out to Rey, nor her hug of consolation with General Organa as such. Is there any evidence that Luke is Rey’s father?

**Is it known who Rey’s parents are?**

Comment: I was eager to post an answer to this based on the title, then realized my previous answer was the one that prompted it! I don't think we'll know for another episode or two, but +1 because I'm eager to see this discussed.

Comment: General FYI on spoiler policy: you do not need to include a spoiler warning. Instead, your title should be totally spoiler free and your question should use spoiler markup.

Comment: I think one of the trailer videos is a major hint too. "The force runs strong in my family, I have it, my father has it, my sister has it, you have that power too". That wasn't actually in the movie I think

Comment: @IvoBeckers: I figured that he was talking to Ben Solo.

Comment: True, that could also be the case

Comment: Updated my answer. Please note that the film's script seems to contradict accepted answer - luke does NOT start to cry, he merely looks tormented, and it is NOT over Rey.

Comment: You can read my answer to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127303/are-rey-and-luke-skywalker-connected/127312#127312

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that she's the offspring of Jar Jar and Mon Mothma.

Comment: You are going to have a hard time finding any evidence. I think the producers have made it clear that Rey's parentage is not only supposed to be a secret but also unknowable for the time being. It is not a thing that could be discovered by poring over the currently available material.

Comment: See also http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44936/9391 "Who is Rey’s family?"

Comment: Her parents names are Dathan and Miramir - https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/star-wars-rey-parents-names/#:~:text=But%20a%20new%20tie%2Din,other%20than%20Dathan%20and%20Miramir. Dathan is Palpatine's clone and Miramir is unrelated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any familial ties between Rey and other characters have yet to be confirmed.

J.J. Abrams did release an answer to a young fan back in April of 2016, stating:

> "Rey's parents aren't in Episode VII. So I can't say in this moment who they are. But I will say it is something that Rey thinks about."

J.J. Abrams later restated this remark later on:

> "What I meant was that she doesn't discover them in Episode VII. Not that they may not already be in her world."

I always took this statement as Rey's parents aren't discovered in Episode VII, so it is up for debate if they are or aren't. 
J.J. Abrams is not directing Episode VIII, Rian Johnson is. J.J. Abrams has also released statements expressing his wishes to respect and value the secrecy to the film:

> "Obviously it is not for me to talk about in this moment because this is Rian's story to continue now. The last thing I'm going to do is reveal something that he would be upset about. I want to make sure that Rian gets the courtesy he showed me."

Daisy Ridley also stated she knows who Rey's parents are, but that it is the journey of the character, rather than her parentage that is important. 
Episode 9 director, Colin Trevorrow hinted that Rey's parentage might not be discovered until Episode 9. But he has stated that Rey's father **is** someone that we have met before in the Star Wars universe.

> "We're going to make sure that the answer is deeply and profoundly satisfying. Rey is a character that is important in this universe, not just in the context of TFA, but in the entire galaxy. She deserves it. We'll make sure that the answer is something that feels like it happened a long time ago, far away, and we're just telling you what happened."

Colin Trevorrow went on to state that Luke and Leia would have more prominent roles in Episode 9, and that he's excited to find "new places to take these characters."

Ian McCaig, who was a former artistic director of Lucasfilm and worked on previous films' storyboards and concept art, gave teasers concerning Rey's parentage. He stated in early drafts of the TFA, there was going to be a romantic teaser between Qui-Gon Jinn and Shmi Skywalker. This was scraped as they did not want any material from the prequels. Despite Disney's insistence, some of these concepts remain throughout the Star Wars universe. McCaig ended his statement with:

> "and now we have a new Skywalker."

In short, Disney and Lucasfilm are teasing who Rey's parents are but we are going to have to wait for the whole trilogy to wrap up in order to find out. Speculations and theories are fun and enjoyable, but at the end of the day, we are left with no real, solid answer. We'll know who Rey's parents are..in time. But it doesn't seem like any real confirmations or answers are going to be let out any time soon.

## Update for *The Last Jedi*

In *The Last Jedi*, [Rey's parents are revealed to be](http://comicbook.com/starwars/2017/12/13/star-wars-the-last-jedi-reys-parents-revealed-kylo-ren-skywalker/):

> random people who were junk dealers who sold and abandoned their child. They are currently dead; buried on Jakku

However, in [an interview with Rian Johnson](http://ew.com/movies/2017/12/16/the-last-jedi-spoiler-rey-parents/2/), he has also stated that the answer provided in *The Last Jedi* is still up for debate until Episode IX:

> **I can’t speak to what they’re going to do. And there’s always, in these movies, a question of ‘a certain point of view.'** But for me, in that moment, Kylo believes it’s the truth. I don’t think he’s purely playing chess. I think that’s what he saw when they touched fingers and that’s what he believes. And when he tells her that in that moment, she believes it.

In [another interview with Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/that-big-last-jedi-reveal-about-rey-isnt-solved-after-all_us_5a39a21ee4b025f99e130e7f) Rian Johnson further discussed why Rey's parentage is still open for debate:

> **Anything’s still open, and I’m not writing the next film. [J.J. Abrams and Chris Terrio] are doing it. With all of these movies, Obi-Wan’s whole speech about a certain point of view always applies, so I think that you have to always think about the context of how information is given.** But for me, dramatically, that’s why that reveal at that moment made sense.

So it still appears that we'll have to wait for Episode IX to solidly confirm *The Last Jedi*'s parentage claims for Rey.

## Update for *The Rise of Skywalker*

**Caution Up Ahead For Episode IX Spoilers!**

In *Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker*, it is revealed that Rey is

> *The Rise of Skywalker* reveals that [Rey is Emperor Palpatine's granddaughter](https://10daily.com.au/entertainment/movies/a191219biljk/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalkers-major-revelation-had-been-hinted-since-force-awakens-20191219). Her parents are nobodies, however, they sold her on Jakku in an attempt to save her.

However, the film also reveals:

> Rey chooses to believes that the [Skywalkers are her chosen family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker). She is seen at Luke's old homestead on Tatooine in the film's end, and [names herself 'Rey Skywalker'](https://www.cnet.com/news/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-ending-explained/)

Our long-awaited questioning and theories to Rey's parentage have been put to rest...finally.

Comment: It should maybe also be noted that J.J. Abrams has lied about the identities of characters before, as he infamously did when asked about Benedict Cumberbatch's role in Star Trek Into Darkness, so he cannot be entirely trusted to be truthful.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111072/reys-familial-ties-in-the-force-awakens/131925#131925). :/ just in more words.

Comment: Also you might want to rearrange the answer so the actual answer of who she is, is at the top not the bottom.

Comment: I wouldn't say her parents were nobodies, at least one is the product of a certain wrinkly boi getting busy

Answer (score 24):

There are several hints as to her lineage. But nothing for sure.

> She seems equal or better in innate force ability to Kylo Ren, who is a third-generation Skywalker

And

> She has Anakin's mechanical ability, and with this seemed to understand and fix things easily.

Also

> The map to Luke was found near her. It was hinted in the flashback that she was left there (for safety we assume), and she would be able to find her way when the time was right.

And

> When Maz says that Rey's search for belonging is forward, not back on Jakku, Rey says "Luke".

There is also a lot of imagery linking

> Rey to Luke

Now this could all be misdirection, but I think it is what we are meant to believe after seeing the film.

**From the novel:**

Kylo seems curious as to this girl, from the outset. However when questioning her he decides

> You're nothing special after all?
>  You're just a -- Jakku scavenger?

Even in the trailer Rey says

> I'm no one

However in the final confrontation between Rey and Kylo he says.

> It **is** you

Emphasis from source.

Which implies that whatever suspicions he has (which are never revealed) are correct. Even Snoke says.

> It appears that he [Kylo] May have been right about the girl.

As to quite who she is is still unclear, but it is clear that she is known to the First Order, more than she is even to herself.

Comment: The word used in that scene was _'belonging'_, not _'family'_. Otherwise, spot on analysis. Thanks.

Comment: "When Maz says that Rey's search for belonging is forward, not back on Jakku, Rey says "Luke". - now she doesn't. At least not in the novelization.

Comment: I've not got there in the novel yet. I believe the scene may have changed quite a lot in production. So will be interesting to see how book and film differ.

Comment: the movie would have been even better is Snorks were involved - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snorks

Answer (score 16):

I didn't see any evidence in the movie that suggests who her parents really are. The two theories are Han and Leia, or Luke and "someone."

> Han and Leia seem unlikely as you would expect their reaction to a "force sensitive girl being found on Jakku" a bit strange and would have to have known who she was.

You listed one point about Luke's lightsaber that could suggest a tie, however the end of the movie suggests an even bigger possibility:

> When Rey finds Luke and presents him with his saber, Luke tears up and starts to cry.

We don't ever see a Jedi show that kind of emotion anywhere in the movies. Now, whether it's because of Rey, or his lightsaber, is still unknown. Nor do we have any idea who the mother would be at this point.

Comment: There is a strange scene near the end, in which Leia (a princess and a general) gets *really* huggy with a random scavanger girl she's never seen before, which makes more sense if one or both of them "recognizes" the other. This seems to be the primary motivation for her being another Solo, but if that's true the rest of Han & Leia's dialogue re: Kylo becomes nonsensical

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: Since they are both force sensitive, I rather think that this is due to their common loss.

Comment: I too felt like it was due to the common loss of Han, but it isnt directly explained.

Comment: @Murch I suspect that was the point of the scene - sharing a common loss. But, I still find that overly, unexpectedly intimate for Leia to act that way in public; especially given that Leia has no idea what Han meant to Rey (and even if she did, it's not even in the same ballpark as what he meant to Leia.)

Comment: Its very unlikely, but maybe Leia is stronger in the force now then they showed, and she could feel much more. She did sense that han had died from across the galaxy. She could have felt the connection between Han and Rey, or at least, she most likely felt Rey's emotions at the time.

Comment: I lean towards the "Luke is her father" interpretation, both because of the reasons listed above, but also because it sets up an interesting conflict: each of these children represent a different facet of the Skywalker clan; Kylo represents the darker side ("He has too much Vader in him"), and Rey the light. It's Luke vs Vader by proxy.

Comment: @irishpanda I agree. it also makes more sense why luke or his unknown wife would leave a child alone on a strange world, then why han and leia would leave their girl but let the boy be trained in the force.

Comment: Also, while the comments above talk about how Leia and whether she recognized her or not, you would think *Han* would, given how much time they spent together through the movie. Han was about to dump both her and Finn off when they recovered the Falcon!

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: Rey and Han had been travelling together and were shown to form a bond, e.g. in the way they have an understanding of the Millenium Falcon. While most Rebels are celebrating the victory after the battle, Leia and Rey are shaken by their loss. They realize this through the force or body language of each other and stand apart to grieve and console each other instead of celebrating. The hug seemed quite appropriate to me.

Comment: Does anyone recall much about the music? Was there any hint of a leitmotif harkening to any of the proposed parents when Rey is introduced?

Comment: So I haven't seen the movie yet...going tonight, but just from the spoilers in the question it would seem that Luke left his light saber with her mother so her mother would give it to her, thus closing the loop when she presented it to Luke. As I said I haven't seen it yet so can't wait!!!!

Comment: @Irishpanda good point I will pay attention tonight to the music

Comment: @escoce You are incorrect. But I shall say no more and let you watch it :)

Comment: Upon further thinking, I realized you can also point to Rey's piloting ability and facility with machinery as further tells to her heritage. Luke certainly inherited those skills from Anakin, so it makes sense she would inherit them from him.

Comment: @Irishpanda Because Anakin and Luke were the only two people in the entire Star Wars galaxy who possessed those skills. I don't think it particularly proves anything.

Comment: I don't think it proves anything, but I do think it is suggestive.

Comment: @Mayshar How do you know that Luke was not into Chewy's castoffs? Hahaha.

Comment: So I have seen it now and although you are correct, this question is also wrong. Luke did NOT tear up.

Comment: Hey very much did. He didnt shed any tears, but his eyes welled up with tears.

Comment: His eyes welled up but there was no other sign of someone starting to cry at all. Not even a slight wrinkle or face movement. That's far fetched. Felt more like emotions from his memories coming back seeing her or the lightsaber.

Comment: @Mayshar no they most certainly did not. The only explanation I have for this "mis-seeing" of tears is two lightly colored moles under Luke's left eyes. They could be mistaken for tears unless one is looking. I have seen the movie twice now, and there is not one shred of emotional reaction from like whatsoever.

Comment: Im watching it again On Friday, but Im pretty positive his eyes got red, puffy and watery. Maybe everyone has a different meaning of "emotions" :) In any case, there isnt any evidence for sure, but I feel like Luke showed emotion that was unusual for Jedi.

Comment: I just saw the movie, and the only reaction I noticed from Luke was what I interpreted as "Crap, I have to stop running away and start taking an active role in events again.  Why did this girl have to come here and make me get involved?".  I didn't see any signs of tears or other strong emotions of any kind.

Comment: Maybe i saw more emotion than other people then, It looked to me like he was about to cry.

Answer (score 15):

## Latest update: (2016/01)

There's still no canon information (for a good reason) but *Star Wars: Episode IX* director Colin Trevorrow told  Entertainment Tonight regarding the theories:

> “I’ve seen all of the theories… What I do know is that **we’re going to make sure that that answer is deeply and profoundly satisfying, because Rey is a character that is important in this universe**, not just in the context of The Force Awakens but in the entire galaxy, and she deserves it. So we’ll make sure that that answer is something that feels like it was—it’s something that happened a long time ago [in a galaxy] far, far away, we’re just telling you what happened.”

Absolutely non-specific, but seems to hint that it is someone meaningful (which, given that Star Wars has always been "the saga of Skywalker family", would likely imply *some* Skywalker).

*Given the updates in the answer below, my prediction as of right now is "Leia is the mother; and someone - possibly but not necessarily - other than Han - is the father".*

---

I know other answers stated "**nothing for sure**", but nobody backed it up with anything concrete or provable.

So my answer will.

I went over the digital version of *The Force Awakens* novelization by Alan Dean Foster, and searched for the following terms:

- daughter
- father
- child
- offspring

**None of them yielded any results pertaining to Luke or Rey.**

---

**UPDATE**

One thing which reflects poorly on Rey being Luke's daughter theory is the actual script for Episode VII.

When describing the last scene, it says:

> IT IS LUKE SKYWALKER.
> Older now, white hair, bearded. He looks at Rey. A kindness
> in his eyes, but there's something tortured, too. He doesn't
> need to ask her who she is, or what she is doing here. His
> look says it all.
> In response, Rey pulls something from the pack.
> LUKE'S LIGHTSABER.
> And she holds it out to him. An offer. A plea. The galaxy's
> only hope.
> HOLD ON LUKE SKYWALKER'S INCREDIBLE FACE, amazed and
> conflicted at what he sees, as our MUSIC BUILDS, the promise
> of an adventure, just beginning...

Now, may be things are different for a Jedi, but when you see a daughter you haven't seen for 15 years, **you are far more likely to move to hug her**, than to wait for her to give you Excalibur like some Lady of the Lake watery tart.

Please note that " He doesn't need to ask her who she is" isn't much of a clue - since he ALSO knows "what she is doing here", he knows about her through the Force, not merely remember his child from the past.

---

UPDATE 2:

I won't repeat them here, but I posted 2 separate answers which basically - in great detail - demolish nearly any chance of Rey being Han's daughter:

[What evidence is there that Han acts unusually remorseful towards Rey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112191/what-evidence-is-there-that-han-acts-unusually-remorseful-towards-rey/112192#112192)

[What do Han and Luke know about Rey's abandonment?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112107/what-do-han-and-luke-know-about-reys-abandonment/113099#113099)

---

UPDATE #3:

And the WGA script is now saying Leia gives Rey "mother's" embrace

> The two women move for each other. And Leia takes Rey's
> face in her hands. Despite her heartbreak, she is grateful.
> She embraces Rey. **A mother's embrace.**

Read that as you will. Is she Rey's mother? Is she merely treating her as a mother, given her permanent-now loss of a son?

Comment: The last moment of the movie is that stare, though. No time passes -- it's just a camera pan around that moment in time. I would imagine that to effectively be the end of the novelization as well. There's no reason to hold that against the theory.

Comment: "Now, may be things are different for a Jedi, but when you see a daughter you haven't seen for 15 years, you are far more likely to move to hug her" Not when you abandoned her on Jakku to live her life as a creditless scavenger. Then you just look at her and feel real, real bad about your life choices.

Comment: Maybe Rey is the Force Reincarnation of Shmi...

Answer (score 8):

There is one indication in the film that **Luke Skywalker is not one of the people who left Rey on Jakku.** And throughout the film, Rey refers to the people who left her on Jakku as her "family."

In the basement of Maz Kanata's castle

> when Maz finds Rey after her lightsaber hallucination, Maz talks to her about returning to Jakku to wait for her family, or continuing on her new adventure. "You already know the truth," Maz says. "They're not coming back. But there's someone **else** who could." "Luke Skywalker," Rey responds.

(I saw the film today, so this should be fairly accurate, but I am paraphrasing. I'd be interested to hear how this dialogue goes in the novelization.)

The film makes it pretty clear that the people who left her were "her family," and the dialogue above seems to suggest that Luke is not one of those people.

Of course, doesn't preclude Luke being *related* to the people who left her and there's always the chance that Maz is pulling an Obi-Wan and lying to Rey. We'll have to wait for the next Episode (or maybe longer) for real answers, but seems very unlikely that Luke is her immediate parent.

Comment: FYI: Other interesting non-Skywalker theories I've heard are that she's related to Obi-Wan, Palpatine (my pet theory), or that she's a Jedi youngling/orphan from Luke's academy who was hidden away after Kylo Ren destroyed the new Jedi Order...

Comment: In thirty years you cannot have a twenty-ich granddaughter.

Comment: @PStag Yep... removed that.

Comment: One thing I'd like to note: leaving Rey on Jakku may not necessarily match with being her parent.

Comment: @PStag...with embryo storage (or stasis fields), anything is possible.

Answer (score 7):

You guys forgot one:

> She could sense Luke. When Rey was being interrogated by Kylor Ren, he read her mind and said "You want to escape. You see an ocean, and an island".

Comment: Is it by now confirmed that it was specifically Luke's island he saw in her head? I know people speculated it was but never saw any confirmation.

Comment: @DVK That all struck me as a classic escape fantasy.  Seclusion on a beautiful tropical island to get away from it all.  There are numerous global enterprises built solely around fulfilling this fantasy.

Comment: That was my interpretation too, that her "escape fantasy" was memories from her youth.

Comment: @DVK  I doubt Rey would have been familiar with worlds other than her own, given her response when landing on Takodana, to the effect of "I didn't know there was this much green in the galaxy."

Comment: This is a possible theory, but there's ZERO canon support that she "sensed" Luke (as opposed to: Had a memory of an ocean - we don't know where she grew up; or had a memory of a holodrama about ocean; or had a force-future-vision of an ocean)

Comment: Even _if_ that was Rey sensing Luke, what does that have to do with Rey's parentage? This post doesn't answer the question being asked. :)

Comment: Luke: "He can feel when I'm near". Vader: "I have felt him, my master". Emperor: "Strange that I have not". All infer that familial ties facilitate force sense. You're right, though. It's not an explicit link.

Answer (score 4):

This is answered in *The Rise of Skywalker*. Rey is actually

> A Palpatine, Emperor Palpatine’s granddaughter to be specific.

However, at the end of the film she

> Takes on the Skywalker name because of Luke and Leia.

Answer (score 2):

## Rey's Parents aren't in *The Force Awakens*, according to Abrams.

Rey's Parents aren't in *The Force Awakens*, so presumably Luke Skywalker is not Rey's father. This was [confirmed](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/star-wars-jj-abrams-reveals-big-clue-about-024438518.html) by the film's director J.J. Abrams himself.

> ABRAMS: Rey’s parents are not in Episode VII. So I can’t possibly say in this moment who they are. But I will say it is something that Rey thinks about, too.

He also added,

> ABRAMS: What I meant was that she doesn’t discover them in Episode VII. Not that they may not already be in her world.

This still seems to indicate that **Luke is not her father** as Luke *was* 'discovered' by Rey in the film, while we know her parents weren't. It is unlikely that J.J. Abrams would say "Rey's Parents aren't in The Force Awakens" in the first place if Luke were actually her father.

Comment: eh I dunno. Luke doesn't discover that Vader is his father or that Leia is his sister but he interacts with both of them prior to both reveals.

Comment: @NKCampbell I don't think Abrams would say what he did if Luke actually was her father though. :)

Comment: Episode VIII will probably open with "Rey... I am your father" or "Thank you, but your father is in another castle"

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 clues at the beginning of TFA which hint at Rey's parents/family. She has an old helmet she puts on while she eats her dinner, which looks like a rebel pilot helmet. Also, she has a roughly made doll in an orange outfit that looks like a rebel pilot uniform. I guess that one of her parents, or someone she would consider family, was a pilot in the Rebel Alliance.

Comment: [Nope](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132926/whose-helmet-did-rey-put-on) and [nope](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112856/did-rey-have-an-x-wing-pilot-doll). The helmet belongs to a rebel pilot but was one that she found when she was a child. The doll is a depiction of that pilot, not her parent/s