# Did Rey have an X-wing pilot doll?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In my second viewing of *The Force Awakens* I thought I briefly saw a crude hand-made doll in Rey’s home that looked an awful lot like an X-Wing pilot. It appeared to have a helmet and an orange suit with white vest. Am I remembering correctly? She seems to know something about the rebellion so this could make sense.

[image: Luke Skywalker in an X-wing fighter pilot uniform.]

Comment: Yes, she did.  I just saw it, finally, and this was one of the things I kept an eye out for.

Comment: Well, she was a fan...

Comment: I rather suspect that Disney has already sent her a cease-and-desist letter for making bootleg X-Wing Pilot dolls.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, the factbook ['The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary) specifically confirms that it's an "***Alliance pilot doll***".

[image]

More specifically, (according to the in-universe journal '[Rey's Survival Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rey%27s_Survival_Guide)') it's a depiction of **Captain [Dosmit Ræh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dosmit_R%C3%A6h)**, a Rebel Alliance pilot whose helmet Rey discovered when she was a child.

[image]

There's also some good background on the doll to be found in the [Junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

> *She wiped her mouth on her sleeve and took stock of her few
>   possessions. They always brightened her day and reminded her that
>   there was more to the galaxy than life on Jakku.*
>
> ***She had a doll she’d sewn together as a younger girl from the fabric
>   of an orange flight suit.*** A canister stored rare flowers she’d plucked
>   in the desert. Then there was the computer Rey had built out of
>   scavenged parts.

Rey is depicted as being quite clearly smitten with the *idea* of The Rebellion so it's hardly a step of the imagination to think of her as finding their [hunky pilots](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBFwcidw6HM/maxresdefault.jpg) highly attractive in her younger days, or even envision herself as one of them.

> *Last, a banged-up pilot’s helmet she’d found in a Rebellion-era X-wing
>   rested on a shelf. This was something she couldn’t toss away or redeem
>   as salvage. It would be like dishonoring the pilot who had worn it.*

---

This is also backed up by the [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) which describes it as a

> *... handmade doll fashioned from reclaimed orange flight
>   suit material*

Comment: I'd say with the white vest, it's clearly supposed to be an X-Wing pilot. I was talking to someone elsewhere about how even the new Resistance pilots wear orange jumpsuits with white vests.

Comment: That's *chunky*, not *hunky*.

Comment: @Xantec - That just means that there's more of him to love.

Comment: I don't think it had so much to do with the pilots as much as her wanting to _be_ a pilot for the Rebellion.  I doubt she cared very much at all about what the pilots looked like, as long as she was one too.

Comment: @JaneS - She wasn't keen to leave the planet. She could have left at any time but she was waiting for her family to return.

Comment: @Richard That doesn't mean she still didn't dream of being a pilot _after_ her family returned.

Comment: Or dreaming that her family returns so that she can go be a pilot!

Comment: @CreationEdge - That's certainly a possibility. She gets all excited in the film about the idea of crewing for Han, then immediately rows back on it.

Comment: @Xantec & Richard, as soon as I saw Grunberg in a fighter pilot suit I immediately thought *"Oh no! Grunburg is the new Porkins so he's certainly going to die!!!"*

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is yes, she did. I can't seem to find a good picture of it. But this is close:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is laughable to assume that a 10 year girl living a life of deprivation would be weaving romantic fantasies about hunky X-Wing pilots and make the doll for that reason.

It is clearly because she dreams about BEING one - not everything related to a woman or girl character has to boil down to love interest for God's sake. Developmentally speaking, children fantasy play about what they idolize.

Additionally, while it is true she doesn't leave because she is waiting for her family, that doesn't mean she doesn't dream about life off of Jakku. She was left there to a life of virtual indentured slavery. Of course she wants to leave, and see if things would be better somewhere else. She just forces herself to stay because otherwise her family might never find her.

**She wants to BE a pilot.**

Comment: A good point, and one also made in one of the other answers: “…or even envision herself as one of them.” However, this does not really answer the question of whether Rey had an X-Wing doll. It’s more of a comment on Valorum’s answer.

Comment: @Adamant - Did you even click on the link to the hunky x-wing pilot? I feel like the joke flew over your head at hyper-speed