# Can we really trust the Children of the Forest?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Westeros rightfully belongs to them. Why would they help the humans? In the season 6 trailer,

> we see Bran with the Night's King.

And also I heard about the theory that the

> old wizard stuck to the tree who Bran meets may be working for The Great Other. He comes in Melisandre's vision and she certainly thinks so.

Isn’t it more likely that they’re not on the humans’s side?

Comment: Seems any answer would be opinion based, and so potentially not a good question for the site?

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister while at the moment only GRRM knows the "real" answer, I think we can have good speculative / deductive answers **backed up by quotations from the books (or the series)**, which I would not call opinion based.

Comment: Watch the show and find out, surely?

Comment: Can you back you claims with quotes from the book or scenes from previous seasons? The trailer for a new season is not a good place for canon. We can see Bran is standing in the scene you describe, so it is clearly a vision/dream.

Comment: *WHAT ARE THESE “CHILDREN” NOT TELLING US?!?!?!?*

Comment: If you think you can truly trust ***anyone*** in this series, then I have a beautiful, pointy tower in central Paris for sale that I might interest you in.

Comment: @Ilfurini the question's premise is based on a short clip from a season 6 trailer. We don't even know that the clip is what it even seems to be. I can see issues with these kinds of questions because the correct answer is always "we don't know yet". But also, both the question and answer will be redundant in time.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister On the one hand some meta questions ([1](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/40711) [2](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6820/40711)) indeed suggest (temporarily) closing questions based on future works; on the other hand questions like this one concerning [Rey's family (Star Wars)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111072/40711) are open and have upvoted answers. Given GRRM propensity to give obscure hints about yet-unknown events, maybe the question could be rephrased: _is there textual evidence of the loyalty/disloyalty of the children of the forest to men?_

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: we don't know yet.

Slightly longer answer: as of April 23, 2016 we don't know. It's certainly a valid question. In the books when Bran reached what seems like the last bastion of the children of the Forest, they did seem to be fighting the White Walkers. The setup seems to be that they don't particularly like Men, but they can survive where Men can not and so simply coexist and do their navel-gazing.

In contrast, the White Walkers seem to want to bring a tide of death over everybody and everything. Thus, whether Men realize it or not, the Children have made common cause with them.

But even that said, the Children seem to mostly ignore the White Walkers and go about their business of... tree stuff. So perhaps it's simply misleading. There's no real way to know.

Comment: Also legend has it that [the Children of the Forest fought with the First Men against the White Walkers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Children_of_the_forest#History) like 8,000 years ago innit. So if we believe that, there’s precedent for them helping men. (Of course, legend also has it that subsequently, the Andal men invaded and slaughtered a bunch more Children of the Forest, so, uh, yeah.)