# Could another character be influencing Rey from a distance?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, rey

I wondered if Rey could be controlled by an outside influence? 
Sometimes, especially when she was engaged in combat with

> Kylo Ren, when she tries to commune with the Force, could she be controlled by Luke? Or could Luke have insufflated how to fight in her?

In Maz Kanata's Castle, what opened the door to where

> Luke's lightsaber was kept? One might say that the lightsaber called to her, but I don't think the Force by itself would have the will to open an electric door.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Could another character be controlling Rey from a distance?

**Possibly.** In Legends, the power of [Force corruption](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick/Legends) could be used to sway people from a distance:

> Force corrupt or Force corruption was a dark side ability that could
>   temporarily manipulate the minds of other sentient beings and make
>   them serve one's own cause. During the Galactic Civil War, it was
>   sometimes employed by the Force users of the Galactic Empire, possibly
>   including Mara Jade and Palpatine himself, taking control of enemy
>   soldiers and making them serve the cause of the Empire by attacking
>   other enemy units.

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51883/long-distance-mind-trick), Jorus Cbaoth and indeed Palpatine were able to control minds over great distances.

These are all *Legends* works, however. Their relevance to the main Disney canon is unclear.

### Is it likely?

**No.**

The answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111039/how-could-a-raw-untrained-force-user-be-so-adept-at-using-the-force) already explain why Rey was able to beat Kylo Ren, even though he had more training than she did.

The door in Maz Kanata's place probably opened because it was motion-activated. No Force necessary.

Comment: Yeah...let's put a motion activated door on our room full of treasures and valuable personal items at the end of the hall just down the stairs from my bar full of mercenaries, smugglers and, most likely, criminals. Great idea.

Answer (score -4):

Possibly. I feel she has a unique ability to use the Force, more so than Darth Vader or any other jedi before her. The Force is an active entity and she seems to display an ability to tap into these abilities like something left dormant in her and then awoke when she touched the lightsaber. It seems as if it's something in her DNA, a intervention perhaps that the Force became so strong within her because the balance of light and dark will always be equal and, with no one else claiming a space as its bearer, Rey managed to claim a very strong hold within the Force in a very short time. Nature, in this way, has a smart way in its survival and will always go against what is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to SS&F SE! You answer is hard to understand, but I think it has some good points in it. Do you have any sources to back up any of these claims? Try to edit you answer to make it clearer what you mean. :) Thanks.